# Setting SessionProperty exception

Tags: mule

I have various mule unit tests that extend my **ABCTestTransformer** - this creates a new instance of **ABCTransformer** but also extends the **AbstractTransformerTestCase**

On the tests when they create a new instance of **ABCTransformer** and get to this line within the transformer in the `public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) method` is where all the tests fail

```
message.setSessionProperty(data here)
```

I keep getting the following exception

> failed with
>   exception(s)[org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Detected
>   an attempt to set a invocation or session property, but a MuleEvent
>   hasn't been created using this message yet.

These unit tests were working with Mule 3.2 but I am migrating to 3.6 and I am now having issues.

Anyone able to shed any light on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the setSessionProperty is already deprecated.

You may try this as an alternative.

```
message.setProperty(yourkey, value, PropertyScope.SESSION);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I tried this already. I saw it was deprecated however it still works.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are setting the value on a wrong sequence, you should call the testEvent first before setting the values. Below is the screenshot, with setting a session variable that works, this is created with lower version of Munit and mule 3.4.

[image]

---

HTH

Comment: I do not have any flows - this is java project compiled as JAR using mule dependencies. This JAR is added as a dependency to our mule project so we can use custom transformers from the JAR etc.